# Clemens-Griffiths component birational invariant

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, say a threefold for sake of better intuition. Is there any geometrical intuition behind the fact that
the Clemens-Griffiths component of the intermediate
Jacobian

$$J(X)= H^1(\Omega^2,X)/H^3(X, \mathbb{Z})$$

is a **birational** invariant. Recall the
Clemens-Griffiths component is called the associated
polarized torus $(J(X), \theta)$ with non-degenerated divisor
$\theta$.

I took some time to look in the proof and
understood the single steps but haven't still any
geometric intuition how to think about it. For example
we know that $H^1(\Omega^2,X)$ is a priori not
a birational invariant, but quotient out $H^3(X, \mathbb{Z})$
seems somehow to play important role in "clearing"
the obstuctions that could occure.

Thinking of blowing up
as archetypical examples for birational transformations,
is there any picture one can have in mind how
$H^3(X, \mathbb{Z})$ "cleans" the defect that in general
prevents $H^1(\Omega^2,X)$ from beeing birational invariant.
Is there any "geometry" behind?

Comment: The geometry is that when you blow up a curve in a threefold, you modify the intermediate Jacobian by adding the Jacobian of the curve. This seems pretty geometric to me.

Comment: At the level of intuition --so a very sloppy comment (I assume that we are speaking about threefolds here).
Suppose you take a (say) smooth threefold and you want to blow it up in a (say) smooth curve. $H^{2,1}(X)$ will not tell you much about the curve you are blowing up (just its genus). However, if you quotient out by $H^3(X, \mathbb{Z})$ then you want to recover the Jacobian of curve, which by Torelli determines the curve up to isomorphism (and smooth projective birational curves are isomorphic). Do not take it as a complete answer, but I found this picture helpful back in the days.

Comment: @abx: where can I find a proof of this fact you have quoted.

Comment: In Clemens-Griffiths of course.

Comment: An excellent modern survey by Beauville: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02476.pdf; see section 3 for the intermediate Jacobian.